# Switch to the Play Referrer API by March 1, 2020 -Google Play

Tags: firebase, google-play, codenameone

I received this email from google play. I only use firebase for push notifications. Im not sure as to what to to here as March 1 is fast approaching.I build my apps using the codename one platform.

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We recently announced that we’ll be deprecating the install_referrer intent broadcast mechanism. Because one or more of your apps uses this intent to track referrals, we wanted to ensure you make the switch before March 1, 2020. After this date, new versions of the Play Store app will no longer broadcast the install_referrer intent after app installs.
>
> Action required
>
> Migrate to the Play Install Referrer API to track your app installs for the following apps and/or games.

All help will be appreciated.

The codenameone libraries I use are:

1. CN1FileChooser.cn1lib
2. ZipSupport.cn1lib

and the build hints are as follows:
`codename1.ios.appid`
`codename1.ios.release.provision`
`codename1.arg.java.version`
`codename1.arg.rim.obfuscation`
`codename1.arg.ios.newStorageLocation`
`codename1.arg.ios.icloud.CloudDocuments`
`codename1.j2me.nativeTheme`
`codename1.arg.ios.project_type`
`codename1.arg.ios.interface_orientation`
`codename1.displayName`
`codename1.android.keystoreAlias`
`codename1.ios.release.certificate`
`codename1.android.keystorePassword`
`codename1.ios.provision`
`codename1.arg.ios.dsym`
`codename1.arg.android.release`
`codename1.arg.ios.statusbar_hidden`
`codename1.arg.ios.NSAppleMusicUsageDescription`
`codename1.languageLevel`
`codename1.android.keystore`
`codename1.vendor`
`codename1.arg.win.ver`
`codename1.arg.ios.NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`
`codename1.ios.certificatePassword`
`codename1.ios.debug.certificatePassword`
`codename1.mainName`
`codename1.ios.release.certificatePassword`
`codename1.arg.ios.prerendered_icon`
`codename1.ios.debug.certificate`
`libVersion`
`codename1.arg.gcm.sender_id`
`codename1.arg.ios.application_exits`
`codename1.secondaryTitle`
`codename1.description`
`codename1.ios.debug.provision`
`codename1.arg.j2me.nativeThemeConst`
`codename1.rim.certificatePassword`
`codename1.version`
`codename1.ios.certificate`
`codename1.icon`
`codename1.rim.signtoolCsk`
`codename1.arg.ios.plistInject`
`codename1.arg.android.debug`
`codename1.rim.signtoolDb`
`codename1.arg.ios.includePush`
`codename1.arg.ios.testFlight`
`codename1.packageName`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the cn1libs that you use and the build hints for the project (with keys redacted) then comment so I get a notification of the update? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ShaiAlmog as requested I have updated the question to include the libraries installed as well as the keys on the build hints

Comment: Try adding the following build hints:
`android.playService.base=true`, `android.playService.gcm=true` and if you use location services: `android.playService.location=true`.

Answer (score 0):

You might only be using APIs from FCM, but your integration probably also includes Google Analytics, which is also installed by default for a standard Firebase integration.  Analytics automatically will track and aggregate user behavior without you calling any of its APIs, so you are probably getting this email because Analytics is doing exactly that in your app right now, even if you didn't ask for it.

If you aren't actually depending on Analytics to track installations, then there's nothing you need to do here.